# Plotting many Wifi Access Points from Android to mySQL database

Tags: android, mysql, location, wifi, latitude-longitude

I have a few questions regarding an app I needed to develop for my final year project.

Its for an indoor building btw. :D

1) I need to gain access to a constantly changing latitude/longitude using a wifi access points. How do i exactly achieve that using an Android device? For example, my device is connected to one Wifi connection, then it will display a lat/long once requested by user. The thing is, once the user move and request another lat/long location, the coordinates must change too, depending on how far the device from the wifi original source.

2) Then after achieving that, every single lat/long location request made by the user can be saved to a mysql database, directly from the device, so that it can be displayed later on as a location only, without the lat/long coordinate. the user can save the lat/long while adding a Wifi name and location name

3) I guess those 2 are the hardest ones, so the final step would be to view all saved locations only.

Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. This question looks overly broad. Can you break it down into specific questions? (Those should be posted separately though)

Comment: You should read this: [what have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Comment: hi, I only obtain those latitude/longitude through the skyhook SDK. But i want to actually to use the LocationManager included by Google. But I dont know if it supports the different lat/long by same Wifi AP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

N.B. This "answer" is really more of a (long) comment.

1. > I need to gain access to a constantly changing latitude/longitude using a wifi access points. How do i exactly achieve that using an Android device?

   This is potentially a bit [too broad](https://stackoverflow.com/faq#dontask) for SO: perhaps you'll get better answers over at [Computer Science](http://cs.stackexchange.com).

   Wikipedia has articles on [indoor positioning](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indoor_positioning_system) and, more specifically, [wifi positioning](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wi-Fi_positioning_system) which may form a good starting point for further research.

   However, I would immediately observe that [received signal strength](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Received_signal_strength_indication) (as used by [Skyhook Wireless](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skyhook_Wireless)) will be a very poor locator indoors due to the presence of obstructions (such as walls); [time of arrival](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_of_arrival) might be a better choice, but requires additional hardware—the most ready-to-go approach would be GPS repeating, but sadly the use of such systems are unlawful within the EU.

   I suspect your only practical choice may be [GSM positioning](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mobile_phone_tracking), but accuracy from cell towers will be pretty poor: you could instead consider [femtocell positioning](http://www.ee.columbia.edu/~roger/wireless_sensing_femtocells.pdf).
2. > Then after achieving that, every single lat/long location request made by the user can be saved to a mysql database, directly from the device, so that it can be displayed later on as a location only, without the lat/long coordinate. the user can save the lat/long while adding a Wifi name and location name

   This is certainly more [on-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/faq#ask), but I don't see an actual question here.  With which part of this are you stuck?  What is it that you want to know?

   There are already [plenty of questions on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bandroid%5D+%5Bmysql%5D+connect) discussing how to access a MySQL database from an Android device: the most common approach is to go via a webservice, but you *could* connect to the RDBMS directly if your threat model allows.
3. > I guess those 2 are the hardest ones, so the final step would be to view all saved locations only.

   Likewise, I don't see an actual question here.  With which part of this are you stuck?  What is it that you want to know?